# Listening google events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

Could you tell me, how can I listening google analytics (google tag manager) event with native javascript? 
For example:

The client sent this event

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue]);
```

I need to subscribe to this event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`tasks`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks), which allow you to hook into the Google Analytics tracker's execution routine, for instance, hook into the [`sendHitTask`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#overriding_a_task) to retrieve the payload of every hit sent:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

ga(function(tracker) {

  // Grab a reference to the default sendHitTask function.
  var originalSendHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');

  // Modifies sendHitTask to send a copy of the request to a local server after
  // sending the normal request to www.google-analytics.com/collect.
  tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
    originalSendHitTask(model);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/localhits', true);
    xhr.send(model.get('hitPayload'));
  });
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: @ValeraChecha: you're welcome. If it's great, you can upvote :) Helps answers stand out and motivates contributors.

Comment: Just a warning for people who do not follow the link: the code example will break the tracker, since it overwrites the sendHitTask without sending data itself.

Comment: I've changed the example so people understand they need to dispatch the event as normal in addition to doing whatever they want to do with it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [hit callback as per documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback) - a JavasScript function that will be executed after the hit has fired.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I know about this feature, but it's not solve my task( 
I want to listen to all the events that the client sends and I can not get it to add this callback.